# How to extract cross validation error in caret like in cv.glm?

Tags: r, regression, cross-validation, r-caret

I have some randomly generated data that I am trying to build a regression model around. Here is the data:

```
set.seed(1)
x <- rnorm(100)
y <- x - 2 * x^2+rnorm(100)
```

I want to perform LOOCV and find the error that results from fitting the model using least squares. Here is how it is done using `boot`:

```
library(boot)
Data = data.frame(x, y)
set.seed(1)
glm.fit = glm(y ~ x)
cv.glm(Data, glm.fit)$delta
```

```
## [1] 5.891 5.889
```

Is there any way to replicate this using `caret`? I can get this far but I can't figure out if there's a way to extract the error from `model1`:

```
library(caret)
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(x,y)
control <- trainControl(method = "LOOCV")
model1 <- train(y ~ x, data = df, trControl = control, method = "lm")
```

Comment: Hey I was going through the code for cv.glm. It is for K-folds validation and the adjustment is basically for samples that are used > 1 in each fold. You are using LOOCV, so you don't need this adjustment.

Comment: Do you actually mean RMSE of each fold during k-fold CV?

Answer (score 0):

A *print(model1)* statement will give you this. Is that what you were looking for?

```
 Linear Regression 

100 samples
  1 predictor

No pre-processing
Resampling: Leave-One-Out Cross-Validation 
Summary of sample sizes: 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, ... 
Resampling results:

  RMSE     Rsquared    MAE     
  2.69966  0.00130345  1.921879

Tuning parameter 'intercept' was held constant at a value of TRUE
```

Comment: Unfortunately no that I what I am looking for. The printed statement is giving me a summary of the entire model performance (RMSE, Rsquared, etc.). What I am looking for are specifically are two values. The first component is the raw cross-validation estimate of prediction error. The second component is the adjusted cross-validation estimate.